# How to bind select2 and mysql databse with php

Tags: php, json, ajax, jquery-select2

I am trying to bind my select2 input to get results from mysql database, using mysqli connection.I tried several solutions here but have yet to make it work, instead it keeps saying no results found.

The latest I have tried was  the javascript code from https://select2.github.io/examples.html. I am not sure if it is my javascript that is failing me or my php file.

These are my codes, hope someone can point to me where needs to be change.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="Customer" id="Customer"><span style="color:red;">*</span>Customer:</label>
      <div class="col-lg-9">
         <input id="cCustomer" name="cCustomer" class="cCustomer form-control" type="hidden" value="" style="width: 100%" />   
      </div><!-- END col-lg-9  -->
   </div><!-- END col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6  -->
</div><!-- END .form-group  -->
```

I did include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//localhost/1System/select2/css/select2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//localhost/1System/select2/css/select2-bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//localhost/1System/select2/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
```

in my `<head></head>`

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cCustomer").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: "../../autoComplete/autoAddQuotation1.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, page) {
                // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                // alter the remote JSON data
                return {
                    results: data.items
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        //templateResult: formatRepo, // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
        //templateSelection: formatRepoSelection // omitted for brevity, see the source of this page
    });
});
```

Lastly, my PHP

```
<?php
   include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/1System/php/connect.php");//calling connection file

   $conn=dbConnect();
   if (!$conn)
      die("Couldn't connect to MySQL"); /*when server is down, the statement will be showed*/
   $query = "SELECT c.customerID, c.name AS cname FROM customer c WHERE c.name LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper($_GET['q']))."%' or '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']))."%'";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
   $numCustomer = mysqli_num_rows($result);

   if($numCustomer != 0) {
      while(row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         $answer[] = array("id"=>$row['customerID'], "text"=>$row['cname']);
      }
   }else {
      $answer[] = array("id"=>"0", "text"=>"No Results Found...");    
   }
   echo json_encode($answer);
?>
```

I am using mysqli to connect to my database. My connection is working for the other php pages.

`$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);`

To be honest I don really know how should the PHP file look like? anyone can point me towards a good example or a right direction.

PROBLEM:

When I click on the input on my chrome, it indicated as no results found.![enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDAa5.png

Thanks in advance. If my question is duplicated or bad please kindly feedback.

Comment: 1. Check what firebug (or similar extension for other browsers) says. 2. in your JS code `url` param should be an URL, not a relative path. 3. Your PHP code should return `array('items' => $answer)`

Comment: @dragoste how do i check the return result of my php code? I read that people are able to see their json result, but I do not quite know how i can do that. Thanks

Comment: in Firebug -> Console and Network tabs you can review all ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS select2 code worked perfectly for me.

Below is the Doctrine function I used to create the JSON response.

You should be able to adapt this to your mysql/php code.

```
$q = strtolower($q);
$stmt = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getConnection()
        ->prepare("SELECT s.id, s.suburb, s.state, s.postcode "
            . "FROM suburbs s "
            . "WHERE LOWER(s.suburb) LIKE '%" . $q . "%' "
            . "OR LOWER(s.state) LIKE '%" . $q . "%' "
            . "OR LOWER(s.postcode) LIKE '%" . $q . "%' "
            . "ORDER BY s.suburb, s.state"
        );
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

$suburbs = array();
if (is_array($result)) {
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $text = $row['suburb'] . ", " . $row['state'] . " " . $row['postcode'];
        $suburbs[] = array('id' => $id, 'text' => $text);
    }
}
return json_encode(array('items' => $suburbs));
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version 4.0 of select2 works on select tags and no longer on input tags (in either type text or type hidden).
It seems your using this version so you should enhance your code accordingly.